# Why do we not see strong-man athletes competing in olympic weightlifting?

Tags: olympics, weightlifting, strongman

Strong-man is of course filled with quite unique events, but many of its athletes hold world-records in traditional weight-lifting events such as deadlift.
Many of the sport's biggest names are in fact competing at an event (Giants Live) which clashes the Games which suggests there is very little overlap.

Is this due to eligibility (professional/amateur) or some other reason(s)? *Have* there been many notable athletes who are known to have competed in both?

Comment: As a note, [strongman] tag didn't even exist, unless I missed an equivalent tag?

Comment: I wonder how much of it has to do with doping?

Comment: @Joe an interesting point.

Comment: https://www.espn.com/espn/story/_/id/26522096/got-strongman-champ-admits-steroid-use

Answer (score 6):

As far as I can tell, weightlifting (as seen in the Olympics) and powerlifting (as seen in strongman competitions) differ in terms of the required techniques and physique.

[According to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Olympic_weightlifting):

> In comparison with other strength sports, which test limit strength (with or without lifting aids), weightlifting tests aspects of human ballistic limits (explosive strength); the lifts are therefore executed faster — and with more mobility and a greater range of motion during their execution — than other strength movements.

This suggests that a strongman would lack the speed and mobility to compete in Olympic weightlifting, whereas an Olympic weightlifter would lack the sheer physical strength to compete in strongman contests.

I'm sure there must have been athletes that have attempted to cross over from one discipline to the other, but I haven't been able to find any.

Comment: Here is a link to the [revision of the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Olympic_weightlifting&oldid=1035485847) at the time of posting this answer.  (The quoted paragraph is still present [in the current revision](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Olympic_weightlifting&oldid=1172464606) - although it is slightly reformulated._)